# Setting up a server for LAN file sharing and editing with password protection

Tags: networking, file-sharing, client-server

I work in a call center, where there are 2 teams (team1 and team2)

Each team has a supervisor and 10 agents.

Agents in both teams periodically change their positions, so no one uses the same PC forever.

Each supervisor shares files like Word and Excel documents with his agents BUT NOT the same file for 2 agents so, the files MUST be private

Now I want to put a central server for file sharing, where:

```
- There a 2 folders (TEAM-1 and TEAM-2)
- Supervisor 1 can access TEAM-1 and ALL subfolders
- Supervisor 2 can access TEAM-2 and ALL subfolders
- Agents in both teams can ONLY access their OWN folder like AGENT-1, AGENT-2 with a password, so that no agent can access another agent's folder.
- Files remain on the server and are directly edited and dealt with within the server and the agents don't have to take their files with them whenever they change the place.
```

NB: Supervisors and Agents are both beginners with computers so the solution must be very simple and easy to use.

Comment: So you want us to tell you how to create a file server?

Comment: From the requirements, it seems that regular Windows file permissions would easily do the job, as long as each person has their own user account.

Comment: That is true grawity

Comment: @EricF It's mainly how to prevent agents from accessing other agents' folders

Comment: @grawity I don't think that Windows file permissions would do the exact job needed

Comment: It's something like FILEZILLA SERVER but not in a web browser as I need the files editable inplace and not just downloadable

Comment: @Med: Yes, they would work just fine.

Comment: @grawity I tried with FZ SERVER. everyone will go atomaticcally to his home folder depending on the login. everything is just fine except when editing the Word document, it forces the agent to download or open the doc then when saving, the agent will be asked where to save and he will not be able to save to the FTP server

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned word document and FileZilla, so I assume you use Windows and you do not have Active Directory.

It's very simple really, pick one computer to hold your files (your central server), create shared folder called Shared, then in there two sub-folders, say Team1 and Team2. Inside those you create Agent1, Agent2 and so on...

Apply per user permissions on every one of those and you are done. Each new file and folder will inherit permissions from it's parent folder.

EDIT

Given your comments I guess you are not very familiar with file sharing concepts, so try taking a look at this guy explaining it: [Introduction to file sharing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFQhawnWOrI) and [Sharing and permissions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJHFmt6F0Rc). The second one is for Windows server, but same concepts apply to Windows 7 and Windows 8.

You can also find a lot how-tos at [Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com) site and [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com).

Superuser is really not the place for a complete solution guide, so learn this stuff, this will be the simplest solution for end users and in the end of the day that's all that matters for business users. If you feel this is not for you - hire someone to do it, trust me you do not want to tinker around and end up in your worst nightmare two years later.

Oh and BACKUP you shared folder!

Comment: I'm not talking about users in the local computer, I'm talking about generic user/pass combinations like in FileZilla Server, as the agents will access their folders from other computers in the samz LAN

Comment: Yes, I know. Create user accounts on your server and there you go.

Comment: Users like the default Admin and Guest? if yes, how many accounts could it handle?

Comment: Windows can handle as many as you need unless it's a server version, then you have some limits. Create accounts for each Agent and Supervisor. They can be limited accounts so they don't mess something up. So they use their server account to login to server share from any computer.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I will check if it's the right answer for me ;)

Comment: still no solution, I did what you told me with no results

Comment: Well I guess you should learn more about file sharing, or hire an IT person to set it up, this is really a textbook example. If you feel like learning more you can read technet articles or windows support site or watch some youtube videos to get a better idea how this stuff works. I will look for some examples when I'm at my computer to point you in the right direction.